# Emulate copy-paste from Keyboard wedge application in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys, keyboard-wedge

We have an application (written in VB 2005) that reads incoming characters on a virtual serial port (on which a Cognex barcode scanner is connected), validate the stream and send it to the focused object using the `SendKeys`command.

It has worked perfectly for years, but now customers have new software and the `SendKeys` no longer works for a specific field in this software (it works everywhere else but this field). They did some tests and found out that, when they copy-paste text, it works using ctrl-c, ctrl-v.

My question is: how can I emulate those keystroke from our application?

Comment: You can still use `SendKeys` to send more than one key at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `SendKeys`, the control key is `^`. Then any additional keys can follow.

So copy would be:

```
SendKeys.Send("^c")
```

And paste:

```
SendKeys.Send("^v")
```

Instead of copying, you can just directly put it on the clipboard (like you suggested), like:
`My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText("This is a test string.")`

Comment: Ok, so I can send the stream to the clipboard using My.Computer object, then do the SendKeys.Send("^V") ?

Comment: @Dominic Yes exactly. If you need help sending it to the clipboard let me know. I've edited my post to help with this.